# According to vs. pursuant to

Tags: differences, phrase-meaning

What's the difference between

> a) **Pursuant** to your last email, I'd kindly like to ask you ...
>
> b) **According** to your last email, I'd kindly like to ask you ...

I found that 'pursuant' is rather formal style and most often used in a legal context. Would it be wrong to use it in a business email?

Answer (score 2):

"Pursuant" is a very very formal word, out of place in most non-legal contexts; but it has the meaning you want.

"According to your last email", doesn't mean what you want: to me means something like "as you said in your last email", and following it with what I want to do is incoherent.

I would say something like "Following on from", or "Judging from" (if that fits), or "Noting your last email".

Comment: or "Regarding your ..."

Comment: Right! "According to" is merely a reference. "Pursuant to" causes action.